# how to unbind a role/cluster role from a service account in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, devops, rbac

For default service account I have creating clusterrolebinding for cluster role=cluster-admin 
using below kubectl command

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=rbac-test:default
```

cluster-admin role is bind to default service account. 
How to unbind it again from service account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your `kubectl` command it creates the following object:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: add-on-cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: rbac-test
```

You should be able to just delete that object:

```
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin
```